# Laravel With() along side with Where()

Tags: php, laravel

Take as example the following eloquent code:

```
Customers::with('ShippingMode')
    ->with('PaymentMethod')
    ->with('BarCodes')
    ->where(function($query) use ($find)
    {
        $query->where('name', 'like', "%$find%")
            ->orWhere('vat_number', 'like', "%$find%");
    });
```

Now I would like to add more `orWhere` conditions but looking into `PaymentMethod` table, like such:

```
Customers::with('ShippingMode')
    ->with('PaymentMethod')
    ->with('BarCodes')
    ->where(function($query) use ($find)
    {
        $query->where('name', 'like', "%$find%")
            ->orWhere('vat_number', 'like', "%$find%")
            ->orWhere('PaymentMethod.description', 'like', "%$find%");
    });
```

But this does not work as it returns the error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PaymentMethod.descricao' in
>   'where clause'

I know that if I use the old joins it works great:

```
Customers::select('customer.*')
    ->from('customers AS customer')
    ->leftJoin('payment_methods AS payment_method', 'payment_method.id', '=', 'customer.payment_method_id')
    ->where(function($query) use ($find)
    {
        $query->where('name', 'like', "%$find%")
            ->orWhere('vat_number', 'like', '%$find%')
            ->orWhere('payment_method.description', 'like', '%$find%');
    });
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: The variable `$find` can be empty and when it's empty it returns all the results without filter applied, which means I cannot use the `whereHas` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[orWhereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint:

```php
Customers::with('ShippingMode')
    ->with('PaymentMethod')
    ->with('BarCodes')
    ->where(function($query) use ($find) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', "%$find%")
            ->orWhere('vat_number', 'like', "%$find%");
    })->orWhereHas('PaymentMethod', function($query) use ($find) {
        $query->where('description', 'like', "%$find%");
    });
```

Comment: `payment_method` does not exists, also only `description` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

Customers::with(['ShippingMode', 'PaymentMethod', 'BarCodes'])
    ->when($find, function (Builder $query, $find) {
        $query->where(function (Builder $query) use ($find) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$find}%")
                ->orWhere('vat_number', 'like', "%{$find}%")
                ->orWhereHas('PaymentMethod', function (Builder $query) use ($find) {
                    $query->where('description', 'like', "%{$find}%");
                });
        });
    })->get();
```

With `when()` it will only apply the filter when `$find` has a value and it allows you to search on the `Customer` columns with the `where() / orWhere()` and the `PaymentMethod` relationship with `orWhereHas()`.

You can read more about `when()` and `whereHas()` here:

[when](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

[whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)